# change sun wtk J2ME emulator system time from UTC to host local time

Tags: netbeans, java-me, emulation, java-wireless-toolkit

I am working on a J2ME midlet project. I am using Sun WTK 2.5.2_01.
The problem is that the time on the emulator device is UTC but i need it to be my host machines local time. I tried to find a setting in the wtk preferences to no avail.

Is this behaviour normal? can I change it? or how can I work around it?

Comment: How did you fetch system time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this problem myself for ages and I finally figured out a workaround. WTK has a settings file system.config in its lib directory. From there you should find a property:
`"com.sun.cldc.util.j2me.TimeZoneImpl.timezone"`

It was commented away in my file and here you can set which time zone WTK uses. For me setting it as `"GMT+03:00"` worked. However, I suspect that the setting needs to be changed every time summer or winter time begins.

Comment: the real problem is that the emulator's Calendar class uses UTC timezone by default... as anlternative to depending on the device being in a specific timezone, i use the Calendar class and set the timezone of the Calendar, and so am always able to render the local time(or whichever timezone i want).